# how to check with jquery if an element is not first or last in a selection?

Tags: jquery, selection

I need to loop through a selection of elements and need to do things for all elements not first or last in the selection.

I'm having problems getting my selector to work:

```
var set = $('.someElements')
    setLen = set.length;

if (setLen > 2 ) {
    set.not(setLen.first(), setLen.last() ).addClass('someClass')
    }
```

Can somebody point me to the correct way of selecting the "middle elements"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you only want to remove elements from the beginning and the end of the set, you can simply use [`.slice` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
set.slice(1, -1).addClass('someClass')
```

Comment: Actually I like this one better than my own version with each. Simplicity is king...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var set = set.filter(':not(:first)').filter(':not(:last)');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use each for this:

```
$('.elements').each(function(index) {
 if(index != 0 && index < $('.elements').length) alert('Middle Element');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var len = $('.someElements').length;    
$('.someElements').each(function(index){
        if(len > 2){
            if(index != 0 && index != len - 1){
                $(this).addClass('someClass');
            }
        }   
    });
```